# Explanation with equations : Polyfit and Polyvalue

Tags: python, numpy, polynomial-math

Actually i am trying to learn some numpy library libraries but i cannot able to understand how these libraries are working from inside. 
Can somebody explain me polyfit and polyval with equations by putting the value without library
i already checked the numpy documentation

1)[PolyFit Numpy Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

2)[PolyVal Scipy Documetation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html)

I checked on S0 and other places also but everybody explaing this with libraries can somebody expain me these in simple maths?

Thanks in advance

Comment: both docs point at relevant refs where you could look up the math involved, polyfit is actually a wrapper around `np.linalg.lstsq` so you might want to look at that too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module to check the source code for these functions.

For example this will show you the source code for `np.polyfit`:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(np.polyfit))
```